# Unable to access nested Jsp Tags in Freemarker

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, freemarker

I have written a Jsp Tag Library using freemarker as the view template.

`custom.tld` is placed in META-INF/tags/.

My tag Lib is bundled as Jar. `customTag.jar`. 
It has following templates

```
AlertTag.ftl
ButtonTag.ftl
```

`AlertTag.ftl` depends upon `ButtonTag.ftl`.

`AlertTag.ftl`:-

```
<#assign custom = JspTaglibs["http://www.abc.com/taglibs/custom"]>

<h5>${this.title}</h5>
<div class="alert ${this.typeClass} ${this.classes!}">
   <@custom.button btnType="close" <span class="alt">close</span></@custom.button>
</div>
```

This customTag.jar is part of another web-app.

`web.xml`:-

```
<taglib>
   <taglib-uri>http://www.abc.com/taglibs/custom</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/custom.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

Now when `index.ftl` in the web-app tries to use the tag `<@custom.Alert id="abc">` it throws the following exception

```
Expression JspTaglibs is undefined on line 1, column 17 in freemarker/AlertTag.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> assignment: custom=JspTaglibs["http://www.abc.com/taglibs/custom"] [on line 1, column 1 in freemarker/AlertTag.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression JspTaglibs is undefined on line 1, column 17 in freemarker/AlertTag.ftl.
```

I am unable to use the nested jsp tag in freemarker.

---

`AlertTag.java`

```
   Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");

    Template ftlTemplate = cfg.getTemplate(view);
    JspWriter writer = pageContext.getOut();
    data.put("id", id)

    Map<String, Object> rootMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    rootMap.put("this", data);
    Environment environment = ftlTemplate.createProcessingEnvironment(rootMap, writer);
    environment.process();
    //ftlTemplate.process(rootMap, writer);
```

@Daniel, I have used the environment like above but it didn't worked either. Am I using it correctly?

Comment: How do you invoke `AlertTag.ftl` itself?

Comment: I am invoking it from index.ftl in web-app. `<@custom.Alert id="abc">`

Comment: I `assume @custom.Alert` is a custom JSP tag itself, as opposed to a plain FreeMarker macro/directive. So what I mean is how will `AlertTag.ftl` be invoked technically. Because I suspect the JSP tag will create its own FreeMarker engine instance that has nothing to do with that used for `index.ftl`, and thus where JSP taglib support exists at all.

Comment: yes, @custom.Alert is a custom JSP tag. I have written a AlertTag.java file which is defined in custom.tld. In AlertTag.java I am invoking AlertTag.ftl. Let me add that to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem. Thanks to @ddekanny and my colleagues for showing the way.

Adding my template to the current Environment which is created by FreemarkerServlet solved my problem.

```
Environment currentEnvironment = Environment.getCurrentEnvironment();
Configuration cfg = currentEnvironment.getTemplate().getConfiguration();

cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");

Template ftlTemplate = cfg.getTemplate(view);
JspWriter writer = pageContext.getOut();

currentEnvironment.setVariable("this", new SimpleHash(data));
currentEnvironment.setOut(writer);
currentEnvironment.include(ftlTemplate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The custom JSP tag support is just a FreeMarker extension that is implemented via a FreeMarker data-model specialized for this. (It happens to be part of freemarker.jar, but technically it could be a 3rd party extension as well.) This data-model defines `JspTaglibs` variable among others. (Also instead of a Map or a JavaBean the data-model root is from the Servlet scopes layered on top of each other.) This data-model is set up by `FreemarkerSerlvet`.

So when you create your own FreeMarker engine and own data-model in `AlterTag.java`, you cut off all that. Either you try to set up a similar data-model (I don't know if anyone has ever managed to separate that from `FreemarkerServlet`...), or you had to run the template in the `freemarker.core.Environment` that `index.ftl` uses. You can get the current environment from TLS with `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment()`, then you could use an `Environment` method to include your template, assuming the template loader can access that. And so you don't have your own data-model... rather messy.

Thing is, FreeMarker was designed to use its own macro/directive/function capability to make libraries. Some of the developers had this idea that custom JSP tags could be exposed as if they were FreeMarker directives... which is an useful hack if you try to migrate to FTL views but you have a lot of JSP taglibs, and so FreemarkerSerlvet, which itself was added to help you to migrate inside "JSP Model 2" frameworks (a model that is itself a quite awkward hack to force MVC on JSP). If you stretch the JSP support beyond that... right now, chances are high that you will have to dig deep.

Comment: I have made the edit to the question and used environment variable as you told. See the edit above, but id didn't worked. Am not too sure, if I am using it correctly.

Comment: You had to use the *same* `Environment` that `index.ftl` runs within, not a new one (use `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment()`). Mainly to get the same data-model. And you really should not re-create the `Configuration` for each template processing... you lose the template cache each time. Again, I warn you that solving this is probably deep water, and you will have to understand FM, and probably even patch the view servlet. It's not a solved problem.

Comment: BTW, if you successfully share the environment with the main template, then the next problem will be that now the tag templates has no own variable namespace, so they will mess around in a shared namespace, clobbering each other's variable and that's clearly unacceptable. That's why FreeMarker has namespacing via `#import`, but you are not using `#import` here so... it might as well needs patching FM, so you can do that without #import.